# Why does ASP.NET has two files for Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

Created a new project (`Web API` with `MVC 5.1`):

[image]

Why does the project has both `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-theme.css` ?

Which one should I replace when I want the replace the theme ?

P.S. Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859449/why-does-bootstrap-include-a-bootstrap-theme-file) is about LESS and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327543/how-to-use-bootstrap-theme-css-with-bootstrap-3) has an answer related to `Bootstrap 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because bootstrap has two files almost always. `bootstrap-theme.css` contains optional theme.
Quoting http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

> Fonts from Glyphicons are included, as is the optional Bootstrap theme.