# Yeoman MeanJS Generator Showing Bootstrap 2 Buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator

I just tried using the [Yeoman generator for MeanJS](http://meanjs.org/) for the first time and I'm wondering why the Bootstrap buttons are rounded like in Bootstrap 2. My dependencies say that I've installed Bootstrap 3 with the project.

```
{
    "name": "meanjsyoe",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "~3",
        "angular": "~1.2",
        "angular-resource": "~1.2",
        "angular-mocks": "~1.2",
        "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
        "angular-ui-utils": "~0.1.1",
        "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.10"
    }
}
```

The code uses Bootstrap's standard classes...

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more</a>
```

And yet, it looks like this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

meanjs includes bootstrap-theme.css by default (see all.js / production.js). This styles buttons like Bootstrap 2.x. You can just remove the including line if you don't like it.

See also: [How to use bootstrap-theme.css with bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327543/how-to-use-bootstrap-theme-css-with-bootstrap-3)