# What is the difference between bootstrap.css and bootstrap-theme.css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the difference between bootstrap.css and bootstrap-theme.css found in the bootstrap file when we download bootstrap?

Comment: Well this is a valid question, but there is already an answer over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327543/how-to-use-bootstrap-theme-css-with-bootstrap-3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use bootstrap-theme.css with bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327543/how-to-use-bootstrap-theme-css-with-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`bootstrap.css` is the core css for BootStrap that defines all the style for various controls/components, where as `bootstrap-theme.css` defines the themes (gradient/animation) for buttons,dropdown menu,navbar,progressbar,panels.

Most of the times adding `bootstrap.css` is enough for bootstrap to work, but for gradient/animation, you can use `bootstrap-theme.css`.

You can see the difference on [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) and then click on "Preview theme" from the very bottom of the menu on the right-hand side of the page.

Comment: Seems like calling it 'bootstrap-gradient-theme' or 'bootstrap-alternative-theme' would have cut down on some confusion.