# Creating a WebSite from Visual Studios and utilizing bootstrap

Tags: visual-studio-2013, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website i am trying to build more for experience and practice. but i cant seem to get the nav bar to promperly show i dont know if i am referencing it correctly in the html file and also i dont know if my file structure is what it should be. any insight and help would be awesome.

I have seen where the .navbar methods are and they seems to be in the bootstrap.min.css file and i have changed and tried everyone of them to see if the bootstrap navbar will show.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to get the context that I would need just from the image that you posted but I see 2 things. you didn't include bootstrap CSS but you did include the theme. Refer to this SO post for the difference: [What is the difference between bootstrap.css and bootstrap-theme.css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400212/what-is-the-difference-between-bootstrap-css-and-bootstrap-theme-css)

As shown on the getting started page of bootstrap, your index page should have the following entrie

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"     integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I also noticed that you are missing the start to your body tag but you have the closing for it. The browser will try to help you on this one but you should fix it to rule it out.

Comment: thanks that is what i was missing. i thought referencing the file itself was enough. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking and your image I can see there is an HTML error. 
Your nav must be in the body tag.

The head tag must only include scripts, style sheets, meta tags and anything that is not "visible" for the user. The body tag contains everything else. Good luck!