# Is the bootstrap-theme.css file the same for any Bootswatch theme?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootswatch, bootstrap-themes

I'm using [bootswatch](/questions/tagged/bootswatch) themes, and I downloaded the [**Journal**](https://bootswatch.com/journal/) theme (on the **Navbar** click on **Journal**, there you'll see the download files), and I have the option to download a **bootstrap.css** file or a **bootstrap.min.css** (check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23368535/15054795) to see what the **bootstrap.*min*.css** means, but essentially it's the same thing as **bootstrap.css**), so I downloaded the **bootstrap.css** file, and indeed the whole look-and-feel of my website looks like the **Journal** theme.

But when I first created my [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) project, I got in my **Content** folder, also a **bootstrap-theme.css** file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27400212/15054795) what this file is), and this file isn't available when downloading from [**Bootswatch**](https://bootswatch.com/journal/), so I wanted to know **can I use any theme with this *bootstrap-theme.css* or does every theme have a *bootstrap-theme.css* of its own? Because I don't see any *bootstrap-theme.css* when downloading a theme from [Bootswatch](https://bootswatch.com/journal/).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bootstrap-theme.css` is a very old add-on theme specific to Bootstrap 3.x. It's no longer relevant, not used for any Bootswatch themes and should be removed from the project.

Comment: Then why does **Visual Studio** by default add it to a new project?

Comment: That's a visual studio question