# Bootstrap buttons hover unexpected hover color

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have strange behaviour on my bootstrap navbar. When i move mouse over my three buttons the down color of them changing as navbar color. Can you tell me how can i change that - but only for those three buttons as i have more of them on my site so dont want to do the change too all available buttons but only those theree. Here how it looks like.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

inspected button:

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

buttons:

```
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="changeToEn()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span> EN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" onclick="changeToDe()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span> DE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="changeToPl()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span> PL</a></li>
```

navbar code:

```
 <div class="pl">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <!--<img id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" src="111.png" /> -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Oblah</a>
    </a>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                   <li><a href="#feedback" class="de"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Oblah</a></li>            
                    <li><a href="#gallery"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></span> Oblah</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#features"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Oblah</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#faq"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span> Oblah</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>Oblah</a></li>  

                    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs highlight" onclick="changeToEn()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span> EN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs highlight" onclick="changeToDe()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span> DE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs highlight" onclick="changeToPl()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span> PL</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you inspect the code through your browser? You might have a bottom border applied to your buttons

Comment: can you reproduce that in fiddle?

Comment: see main post - inspected button

Comment: There's a transparent background property on hover the anchor link, inspect the element, and disable it, it it works , i'll give you how to deal with it as an answer.

Comment: ok waiting on your support then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following demo

https://jsfiddle.net/7cr08k2b/2/

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a.highlight:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a.highlight:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 0px white;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a.highlight,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a.highlight:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a.highlight:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 0px white;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs highlight" onclick="changeToEn()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span> EN</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs highlight" onclick="changeToDe()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span> DE</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs highlight" onclick="changeToPl()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span> PL</a></li>
```

Comment: `class="btn btn-primary btn-xs highlight"`

Comment: yes i meant in css class //do something i want to be as buttons color

Comment: @StackUser Please see demo above. I have added a button without the class `highlight` to show that that is specific to your three buttons

Comment: hmm maybe when i move over the mouse button should become more "lighty"

Comment: There is nothing wrong in there. There are check boxes next to each css file. check or uncheck them and see what happens every time to your buttons

Comment: See [this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles#trigger-pseudo-classes-on-element)

Comment: my css is linked to remote classes and i have my custom css: :  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">

Comment: have you tried to remove the option theme bootstrap-theme.min.css?

Comment: i removed and now when move mouse over the button is highliting entire on blue color as  navbar

Comment: Is it not fixed then? What do you want to achieve

Comment: I would like to button has not changed its color, and only highlight it a bit to be more "lighty"

Comment: Well done!! [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23522301/2511306) can be very explanatory. Glad it helped :)